# want to extend the width of textbox to the left side instead of right side

Tags: jquery, html

in this code the width of textbox extends to right side but i want to extend the width to left side without aligning the textbox to right side

```js
$("#textbox1").on('click', function() {
  $("#textbox1").animate({
    width: 800
  }, 'slow');
}).on('blur', function() {
  $("#textbox1").animate({
    width: 245
  }, 'slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-
alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-
rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <button id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary">button</button>
        <br>
        <h2 id="accordion" style="display: none;">First Example Of Jquery</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h2>Search</h2>
        <input type="text" id="textbox1" name="txt" class="form-control">
        <button id="btn2" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#textbox1").click(function(){
        $("#textbox1").animate({
            width: '+=50px',
            left: '-50px'
        });
    });
```

it will increase the width 50px to the left. Change the value as needed

Answer (score 0):

This is so wrong from the UX side, but a quick answer is to put put float-right class on the input so it can only extend left.

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1" name="txt" class="form-control float-right">
```